# display file meta data in formatted columns

Tags: files, text-formatting

I need to display file meta data from the current directory in the format below.

The first column should be left-aligned, second centered and third right aligned to the right end of the terminal screen.

Comment: Most Unix filesystems does not store file _creation_ timestamps.

Comment: @Kusalananda, most Linux and BSD file systems do though.

Comment: Do you want those 3 columns separated by a fixed amount of white space, or the first left-aligned, second centered and third right aligned to the right end of the terminal screen?

Comment: What format for those "dates"?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Probably the current locales date representation (`%x`). Everything else about this question is unknown, so why not?

Comment: Do you want those 3 columns separated by a fixed amount of white space, or the first left-aligned, second centered and third right aligned to the right end of the terminal screen?  Ans:- first left-aligned, second centered and third right aligned to the right end of the terminal screen

Comment: What happened to the pertinent information in the question? "File Name                 File Creation Date             Last File access date" and "Solaris"

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `find` (possibly available as `gfind` on your system):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%-58P %TF %AF\n'
```

Would print file name, last modification date (creation date of the content of the file if you like) and last access date in YYYY-mm-dd format.

To restrict to `.txt` and `.bkp` files not accessed within the last 365  days:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
  \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.bkp' \) \
  -atime +364 -printf '%-58P %TF %AF\n'
```

Columns should be aligned as long as file names don't contain control or multi-byte or zero-width or double-width characters and are not longer than 58 bytes.

The first column is left-aligned, third right aligned (assuming a 80 column wide terminal), the second is shifted to the right to leave room for the file names. Adjust the filename width and spacing if you really want it centred.

Note that the file list is not sorted.

With ast-open `ls` (or the `ls` builtin of ksh93 if built with it):

```
ls -AZ '%-58(name)Ls %(mtime:%F)s %(atime:%F)s'
```

Should preserve alignment for multi-byte, zero-width and double-width characters and sort the list.

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat
for f (*(DN)) {
  stat -LH s -F %F -- $f &&
    printf '%-58s %s %s\n' $f $s[mtime] $s[atime]
}
```

To restrict to `.txt` and `.bkp` files not accessed within the last 365  days, replace `*(DN)` with `*.(txt|bkp)(DNa+364)`.

Should preserve alignment for multi-byte characters and sort the file names.

Since there's no standard command to retrieve modification and access time in a reliable way, portably, as usual, your best bet may be to use `perl`:

```
perl -MPOSIX -Mlocale -Mopen=locale -MEncode::Locale -MEncode -e '
  opendir D, "." || die "open .: $!\n";
  for (
    sort {$a->[1] cmp $b->[1]}
      map {[$_, decode(locale => $_)]}
      grep {!/^\.{1,2}\z/}
      readdir D
  ) {
    if (@s = lstat$_->[0]) {
      printf("%-58s %s %s\n", $_->[1],
        map {strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime $_)} ($s[9], $s[8]))
    } else {warn "$_: $!\n"}
  }'
```

Like with the `zsh` approach, it should preserve alignment for multi-byte characters, and sort the file names according to locale collation order.

As Solaris 10 comes with an ancient version of `perl`, you may have to give up support for non-ASCII characters in file names which would simplify it to:

```
perl -MPOSIX -e '
  opendir D, "." || die "open .: $!\n";
  for (sort grep {!/^\.{1,2}\z/} readdir D) {
    if (@s = lstat$_) {
      printf("%-58s %s %s\n", $_,
        map {strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime $_)} ($s[9], $s[8]))
    } else {warn "$_: $!\n"}
  }'
```

To restrict to `.txt` and `.bkp` files not accessed within the last 365  days, replace `!/^\.{1,2}\z/` with `/\.(txt|bkp)\z/ && -A > 365`

Comment: Thanks for script but unfortunately stat command isn't working. I think it's not installed on Solaris 5.10.

Comment: @Akki, `stat` becomes a zsh shell builtin after you run `zmodload zsh/stat`. That code has to run in zsh. zsh is available on Solaris, though not necessarily installed by default depending on the flavour of Solaris you have.

Comment: Thanks, I have 1 script which is showing result at file level. I want to run this script as directory level, So that i can get the details of all files in required format. Please find the script.

Comment: E_NOARG=65
E_MOREARG=66
if [ $# = 0 ]
then
        echo -e '\E[31m' "Usage: $0 <filename>"
        tput sgr0
        exit $E_NOARG
elif [ $# -gt 1 ]
then
        echo -e '\E[31m' "Please give only one file at a time"
        tput sgr0
        exit $E_MOREARG
fi
LS=`which ls`
MOD_TIME=`$LS -lart $1|awk '{print $6" "$7" "$8" "}'`
ACC_TIME=`$LS -laru $1|awk '{print $6" "$7" "$8" "}'`
echo "The modified time of the file is $MOD_TIME"
echo "The accessed time of the file is $ACC_TIME"

Comment: @Akki, you can't parse the output of `ls -l` reliably, see the edit where the last perl command should work on a plain Solaris 10.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked fine. Just want to know can we display the .txt and .bkp file which is not accessed in last 365 days? Thanks again..

Comment: @Akki, see edit.

Comment: Sir, Perfectly fine! Thank you so much for your help!! I got answer of my query.

Comment: Can we write theses output to csv file? I want to write output in csv file also. Thanks

Comment: Can we write theses output to csv or excel file? I want to write output in csv or excel file also. Thanks

Comment: @Akki, yes, perl has modules for writing CSV and MS excel files.

Comment: Can you please help me with same? My requirement is to get output of given script in csv / ms excel files. Thanks

Comment: @Akki, you'd need to ask a separate question for that with clear requirements.